# How I will set ad content filtering for native ad advance in android?

Tags: android, native-ads

Can I set ad content filtering for native ad advance? I got the below code for admob. But how I will implement this in native ad advance?

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("max_ad_content_rating", "G");

AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class, extras)
    .build();
```